# Simple preg_match question

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following regex gets all images src but shows it with `src="` at the begining and `"` at the end of the path.

How can I remove it and show only the path?

```
preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/i' , $content1 , $matches);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Code:**

```
$re = '/(?<=src=")(?:.*?)(?=")/ui';
$txt = '<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6f5de9?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG" height="32" width="32" alt="">';

$nMatches = preg_match($re, $txt, $aMatches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6f5de9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're almost doing it right. The regular expression is correct, but:

```
echo $matches[1];
```

This will output the first captured subpattern. The first match (`$matches[0]`) will always contain the full text that was matched, that is including the `src=""` bits.

Answer (score 2):

$matches will contain the entire matched pattern in the first element, followed by elements for each subpattern. In this case, you want $matches[1] for the stuff you want.